# How to get a five pointed star inside a circle in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I would like to get the following image with tikz:
[image: The result I would like to get]

Thanks who will help me. This is what I done so far

```
\begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}[c]{4\linewidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tikz
            \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
            \ifnum \i<4
            \fill (\i*360/5:3) coordinate (5\i) circle(2.5 pt) node [below,xshift=-4*\i pt,yshift=18pt] {$\i$}
            \else
            \fill (\i*360/5:3) coordinate (5\i) circle(2.5 pt) node [below,xshift=11pt,yshift=5pt] {$\i$}\fi;
            \draw (-3.6,3.2) circle (3 cm);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark left of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Star shape is already available in `shapes.geometric` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[n/.style={circle, fill,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw node [star, star point height=.5cm, minimum size=2cm,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (s) {}
     circle (1) (s.outer point 1) node[n,label={90:1}]{} 
     foreach\x in {4,2,5,3}{--(s.outer point \x) node[n,label={(-45+90*\x):\x}]{}}--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]